# DB2: QCMDEXC RTVCLSRC from System i Access ODBC Driver

Tags: db2, ibm-midrange

I want to get the sourcefile from a DB2 CL Program via the System i Access ODBC Driver.

When I call this in the SQL Editor:

`CALL QSYS2.QCMDEXC('RTVCLSRC PGM(PSAAABBB)')`

I get this error:

```
ERROR: [IBM][System i Access ODBC Driver][DB2 for i5/OS]CPF9802 - 
Not authorized to object PSAAABBB in *LIBL. Error Code: -443
```

I also tried:

```
CALL QSYS2.QCMDEXC('RTVCLSRC PGM(PSAAABBB) LIBL(MAINDB)')
```

but then I get this error:

```
ERROR: [IBM][System i Access ODBC Driver][DB2 for i5/OS]CPF0006 - 
Errors occurred in command. Error Code: -443
```

does anyone know, how this would work?
I think the error is when changing the Library?

Thanks

Comment: This is not a system program, or at least it isn't on my system. Are you sure that you don't already have the source for it? The first error indicates that you don't have authority to the object. Maybe your admin can give you the necessary authority.

Comment: Second try fails because `RTVCLSRC` has no `LIBL` parameter, it has not been called. If you want to specify the library where the program is you have to qualify the program name like this `RTVCLSRC PGM(MAINDB/PSAAABBB)`

Comment: @jmarkmurphy and nfgl: - but maybe is there a way to get to know what the input params of this function would be? - i know I dont have authority, but it is for reverse-engineering an old db. Thanks..

Answer (score 0):

For reverse engineering an IBM i program, you may be out of luck. IBM has put protections in place to allow the author of a program to prevent that.

If the program is a CLP, and you have the correct authorities, you may be able to `RTVCLSRC`. But, the program must have been compiled using `ALWRTVSRC(*YES)`.

Here is a link to the documentation for that command https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/i/7.3?topic=ssw_ibm_i_73/cl/rtvclsrc.html but you still have the authority issue, and potentially the issue that the author of the program did not compile with ALWRTVSRC(*YES). This is common with commercial software.

If you are looking for the parameters of `PSAAABBB`, then you are out of luck without the source. You might be able to find the number of parameters using `DSPPGM`, but the data type, length, and purpose of each parameter would still be a complete guess. There is no reflection API to let you discover this. It would be all trial and error. but without authority to the program, you cannot even do that.